# Manage version on Assembly-C-Sharp.dll generated by Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, wix, windows-installer

The versioning on the file Assembly-C-Sharp.dll created by Unity 3D which contains all user scripts seems to arbitrarily increment and varies between machines building them. Is there a way we can manage the versioning on this file?

The reason I ask is that our installer technology (Windows Installer: .msi files using Wix) does not support upgrading an installation where some dll files decrease their version. As a result after upgrading to a lower version the entire file will be removed causing a corrupt installation.

There are several workarounds to remedy this, but none of these work for us. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2015/11/16/why-windows-installer-removes-files-during-a-major-upgrade-if-they-go-backwards-in-version-numbers/